# Queens exercise in java using stacks

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm kind of new to programming, and i have this assignment to solve the N Queens problem.
I don't know what wrong with my code, and i kind of spent a lot of time. 
Could anyone help me out by guiding me to the right direction ?

```
public static boolean isSafe(int[] col, int size, stack s)
{       
    int x;

    for(int i = 1; i<=size; i++)
    {
        if(s.get(i)==i || ((s.get(i-1) - s.get(i)) == (col[i-1] - col[i])))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void solve(int size, stack s)
{
    int[] column = new int[size];
    int x = 0;

    s.push(0);
    column[0] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<size;j++)
        {
            if(isSafe(column,size) == true)
            {
                s.push(i);
                column[i] = j;
            }
            else
            {
                x = s.pop();
                if(x+1<size)
                {
                    column[i] = x+1;
                    s.push(x+1);
                }
                else
                {   
                    j=0;
                    column[i] = j;
                    s.push(i+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(s.size() == size)
        printBoard(column, size);
}
```

The stack class, has a push, pop, size, get functions (returns int and the parameter for the push function is an int)

I only need to solve it using backtracking and stacks, no recursion.

Edit: Btw if i changed

```
if(s.size() == size)
  printBoard(column, size);
```

replaced size variable to 1, i get the board printed else i get nothing.

Edit:
The problem is with the push and pop, the algorithm is not quite correct because i'm ending up with only 1 element in the stack.

Comment: Please be a little more specific. What is it that doesn't work? Do you get an error? Or do you just get the wrong answer?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg There's something wrong in my code, I'm not getting an error. But when i call the print function to print the board, i don't see anything.

Comment: Your logic appears to be oriented towards a check for isSafe(column,size)==true but is testing for false, instead.

Comment: @phatfingers i just changed it to true, same problem.

Comment: Hopefully, it's a different problem now, yes?  If I understand correctly, you want your program to place size=N queens onto a chess board in such a way that they can't attack one another.  Start with size=1 and get it working first.  I think you'll find that i should be zero-based, not one-based in your initial loop.

Comment: what does your code look like now? having update if conditions and the isSafe() method?

Comment: I edited the post, as i said i think the problem is with the push/pop in the loops, I'm ending up with only 1 element in the stack.

Comment: have you changed the isSafe() method to accept the stack being passed in?

Comment: @rhinds yes i did, i created 1 instance in the main, and passed it to the other functions, ill edit the post.

Comment: Is the stack class your own implementation? or the standard Java Stack class? I would have thought that you would get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception if you tried to run the above code on the standard Java Stack implementation (isSafe calls the .get(i) method, where i=1, and on first call stack size is only 1)

Comment: It's my own implementation, but it's working fine. The problem is with the loop. I'm pushing and poping in a wrong way.

Comment: ok, so in your implementation, if stack is size 1, and you call stack.get(1) (assuming get(0) gets the first position) what will you implementation return? (this is where java Stack would throw an error)

Comment: I am returning a negative number only. I didnt throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify for anyone interested, the "N Queens" problem is reminiscent of the "8 Queens" problem in which 8 queens must be placed on a chess board such that no one queen can capture another. This can be extended to any number of queens (so long as the chess board has the appropriate dimensions). The puzzle lends itself well to recursion and is often taught in chapters on recursion. Here's a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) to the puzzle.

You say that you're allowed to use a `stack` but not `recursion`. Recursion actually works by using a stack (which you never explicitly interact with). This means it's possible to write any recursive function by instead using a stack. In this situation, a stack is used to keep track of function parameters and other related variables. More specifically, when a new recursive function is called, all of the current local data in the function is pushed onto the stack. When the data needs to be retrieved after exiting a recursive call, the data at the top of the stack is popped out and then used again.

It might be easier for you to first write a recursive function to solve the problem, then figure out how to "convert" the recursive solution into an iterative one with a stack. It's also a good idea to try writing the solution iteratively, then figuring out what information needs to be kept track of for backtracking to work. I noticed that you're also using a 1D array to store the positions of the queens, but it might be useful to better visualize the puzzle by using  2D array first. This also makes your programming more straightforward.

Comment: I agree. I actually need to use a iteratively rather than recursively. I'll go with a 2D array,i think its the best way. The 1D array is only to store the column, i'm actually storing the rows in the stack. I thought of changing my own implementation of the stack to return an array with a row and column.

Comment: A 1D array is very efficient, but it can be "tricky" to implement. Also, you shouldn't store an array in your stack. It would be a better idea to push and pop *two* values onto the stack every time (row and column): `stk.push(row); stk.push(col)` and then to retrieve: `col = stk.pop(); row = stk.pop()`

Comment: mmm, that's even better. Will do as you said. I'm just not yeat about my algo about the solve and check function. Did you check them ? I still doubt...

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's 'yeat'? You haven't provided an implementation using a 2D array. You'll need to rewrite each of your functions to accommodate the change.

Comment: ah sorry, i was typing a bit fast. I meant, "I'm just not yet sure about my algo posted above" without any change, i only wanted to know whats my mistake in the current code. Anyway thanks for your reply, I'll work on it now.

Comment: I haven't spent the time to fully understand a 1D solution, but try implementing the 2D array version first and edit your original post with details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the N Queens problem, and as the commenter mentioned, Im not sure what the problem you are facing is, but here are two quick observations:

1. in you isSafe() method you initialise a new stack (so will be empty) and then you immediately perform checks in the if condition to determine its content - so this method will always return true - Did you mean to pass the stack you created in the main method through to this?
2. Very minor observation, but when performing if statements on booleans you dont need the "==false" - if(!isSafe(column,size)) is enough (notice I added the ! for checking false)

Comment: I did as you said, i created an instance of my stack in the main and passed it to the other functions. Still having the same issue.